# Errors with Excel Worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, worksheet

I'm writing a program to write data to an existing Excel file. Plan to append the new data to the old one but right now I'm stuck at trying to access a specific worksheet. I did a lot of search online but none of the things people did work on mine at all. I still get errors. Hope someone can help me figure out what I did wrong. I have a function to write to Excel. 
I have been stuck at the line to create the worksheet object. Always get error on this line.
I have tried different ways like:

```
Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorksheets.get_Item(1);
```

or

```
Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorksheets.Worksheet[0];
```

or

```
Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorksheets.get_Item(1);
```

or

```
Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorksheets.get_Item(currentSheet);
```

I tried many different ways I found online but none of them seem to work for me.

Here is the function of my Excel code:

```
using Microsoft.Office;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public void write_to_file(string lux_excel, string serialnumber_excel)
{
    Excel.Application excelapp = new Excel.Application();
    excelapp.Visible = true; //make the object visible
    Excel.Workbooks excelWorkbooks;
    Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook;

    excelWorkbooks = excelapp.Workbooks;

    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    string fileName = @"C:\Designs\C_sharp_learn\chapter2\test_data.xlsx";
    excelWorkbook = excelWorkbooks.Open(fileName, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
    string currentSheet = "Sheet1";
    Excel.Sheets excelWorksheets = (Excel.Sheets)excelWorkbook.Sheets;
    Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorksheets.get_Item(1);

}
```

Comment: And the error is.....?  Saying you have an error but not telling us **what** the error says is like going to the doctor, telling him you don't feel well, and expecting him to give you a diagnosis based on that.

Comment: The error is 'one of more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?' This is the error specific to this line: Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorksheets.get_Item(1);

Comment: It looks like whenever I type Excel.WorkSheets excelWorksheets = (Excel.Worksheets)excelWorkbook.WorkSheets; I get an error saying The type or namespace name 'WorkSheets' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel' (are you missing an assembly reference?) but shouldn't it exist??

Comment: You're missing a reference.  Check your references. The error about a dynamic expression is because the .Net Framework has dynamic objects, which was built in large part to help with COM Interop.  The problem is you're trying to use a dynamic property (Sheets) and the .Net Framework doesn't understand what you mean by that.  You're missing some references to work with Excel.  What namespaces are you importing?

Answer (score 5):

Add Reference `Microsoft.CSharp`. Solution explorer window: References -> Add Reference -> .NET tab, add `Microsoft.CSharp`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what error you're getting, but I've done the following to access worksheets in an Excel workbook via COM Interop:

```
_xApp = new Excel.Application();                
_xApp.DisplayAlerts     = false;            // don't display alerts             
_xApp.AskToUpdateLinks  = false;            // don't present the option to ask for link updating                
_xApp.ScreenUpdating    = false;            // turn off the redrawing the of the screen while we're working

// open the book
_xBook = _xApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename: _file.FullName, UpdateLinks: false, ReadOnly: true, CorruptLoad: true, Editable: false, Local: true);

_xBook.CheckCompatibility   = false;
_xBook.UpdateLinks  = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlUpdateLinks.xlUpdateLinksNever;
_xBook.Activate();

_sheets = _xBook.Worksheets;

// get the sheet we want
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.WorksheetName))
{
    for (int i = 1; i < _sheets.Count + 1; i++)
    {
        _xSheet = _sheets[i] as Excel.Worksheet;

        if (base.CheckFilter(this.WorksheetName, _xSheet.Name))
            break;

        if (_xSheet.Name.IndexOf(this.WorksheetName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
            break;
     }
 }
 else
 {
     _xSheet = _sheets[1] as Excel.Worksheet;
 }

 if (_xSheet == null)
     throw new ArgumentException("Worksheet not found in Excel Spreadsheet provided!", "this.WorksheetName");

 _xSheet.Activate();
```

I think the problem is with your use of Sheets instead Worksheets.  Without knowing your specific error, it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Hi @Marurice Reeves: I tried first Excel.WorkSheets excelWorksheets = (Excel.WorkSheets)excelWorkbook.WorkSheets; but I got this other error: 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook' does not contain a definition for 'WorkSheets' and no extension method 'WorkSheets' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) So I looked up online and found someone said need to use 'Sheets' instead of Worksheets.

Comment: After I changed to 'Sheets', I don't this error for this line anymore but I get another error for the next line as I posted for this above.

Comment: Just coding style.  Some places I've worked require them.  I don't quibble  I just do what they tell me.

Comment: Keep seeing I'm getting downvoted for this answer, and I'm not sure why. Can the folks who are downvoting me at least explain why they're doing so?  It would help make the site better, and help future users too.